# updating MYSQL table gives success msg, but does'nt update the table

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

the AJAX msg gives successful, but the data doesn't update in DB, can you help plz!

html code:

```
<div class="row">

                        <input  type="text" ng-model="updateId" class="form-control" placeholder="user Id To Update Phone">
                        <input  type="text" ng-model="updatePhone" class="form-control" placeholder="user New Phone">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2">

                        <button ng-click="updateuser()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Update </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

javascript code:

```
  $scope.updateuser = function () {
                var data = {
                    updateId: $scope.updateId,
                    updatePhone: $scope.updatePhone
                };

                $.ajax({
                       data: data,                          
                       type: "post",
                       url: "update.php",
                       success: function(data){
                            alert("Data Updated");
                       },
                       error:function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                if (textStatus == 'Unauthorized') {
                                    alert('custom message. Error: ' + errorThrown);
                                } else {
                                    alert('custom message. Error: ' + errorThrown);
                                }

                        }
                    });      

            };
```

update.php code:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');
include 'connect.php';
$db = new database();
$db->setDb_name('training');

$db->connect();


if(isset($_POST)){ 
$id = $_POST['updateId'];  
$phone = $_POST['updatePhone'];
$data =   $db->update('user',array('phone'=>$phone),array('id',$id));
echo json_encode($data);

}

mysql_close();

?>
```

the update() function:

```
public function update($table,$rows,$where)
{

        for($i = 0; $i < count($where); $i++)
        {
            if($i%2 != 0)
            {
                if(is_string($where[$i]))
                {
                    if(($i+1) != null)
                        $where[$i] = '"'.$where[$i].'" AND ';
                    else
                        $where[$i] = '"'.$where[$i].'"';
                }
            }
        }
        $where = implode('=',$where);          
        $update = 'UPDATE '.$table.' SET ';
        $keys = array_keys($rows); 
        for($i = 0; $i < count($rows); $i++)
       {
            if(is_string($rows[$keys[$i]]))
            {
                $update .= $keys[$i].'="'.$rows[$keys[$i]].'"';
            }
            else
            {
                $update .= $keys[$i].'='.$rows[$keys[$i]];
            }

            // Parse to add commas
            if($i != count($rows)-1)
            {
                $update .= ','; 
            }
        }
        $update .= ' WHERE '.$where;
        $query = @mysql_query($update);

    }

}
```

I am using angularJS, and when trying to run updating in update.php it works correctly, but using AJAX it gives "Data Updated" msg but actually doesnt update table.. why?

Comment: i think you have problem with php file  .. check the php error on network

Comment: You said update.php works correctly. How are you posting data to the script for testing?

Comment: when i run update() function in seperate php file, it works well and update the data,, is that what you mean?

Comment: do i write the update() function? if you want to see it?

Comment: As you are using a class we have no information about, its difficult to be any help. **Show `$db->update` at least** Also you are not doing any error checking so how would you know what is going wrong

Comment: I wrote the update() function :))))

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the ajax success callback from (I'm assuming) jQuery just means the HTTP request succeeded. This means it got a 200 response code. With most minor and some major errors in PHP the request will still be successful. If you want to know what went wrong, enable error reporting in PHP and be sure the errors are displayed:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Now, you should be able to see any errors. Use something like Chrome's developer console to see what error happened in your PHP code. Another option would be to log the error in PHP and check the error log after the request.

Comment: I wrote this code in php file but it doesnt show any thing

Comment: Make sure the update function is working properly. Another note: The update function will always be called, $_POST should always be set, it will be an empty array when no variables are set. Check for this with $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'

What is the developer console showing you about the request? What status code does it return and what are the contents?

Comment: Please remove the @ before mysql_query, it will suppress the error you are probably missing at the moment.

Comment: I removed @ and nothing happened

Comment: can you echo the query before you execute it?

Comment: The Firebug response is ''null' ... is the error here?

Comment: You do not return anything in the update function. This explains the "null" in firebug. But this does not explain why your data is not updated. Could you post the query which is executed? Just echo the query before you execute it.

Comment: I writed `return $query;`  in update() function and it returns false!! why?

Comment: Because your query contains an error. Did you add the error reporting statement at the top of the update file? Please put it a the top and remove the @ from mysql_query if you added it again. It should show you the error.